# Add multiple choice score

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to add up the score in a multiple choice quiz.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time, os, random

global questions

questions = []

questions = ['''
What does ? equal to:

43+(5x(6)**8)/8-8+8 = ?

1) 10356
2) 1049803
3) 202367
4) 12742130
5) 343321

''',
'''
Find the range, the median, the mode and the mean:

>>> 232, 4343, 434, 232.4, 43, 5453, 434, 232, 645, 23.3, 53453.3, 434 <<<

1) 53410.3, 2943.5, 434, 5496.58
2) 53410.3, 5956, 434, 5453.28
3) 232, 43, 3452, 421, 642
4) 232, 43, 43, 434
5) 232, 5453, 645, 53453.3

''',
'''
In 2004, the minimum wage in Ontario was $7.15.
In 2008, it was $8.15. What is the rate of change?

1) $0.90
2) $3.98
3) $1.54
4) $0.40
5) $1.80

''',
'''
Find the value of n:

--------------------------------------

    43n/2n  x (99.99/9)x7 = 99.99n  

--------------------------------------

1) n = 99.92
2) n = 12.43
3) n = 16.73
4) n = 104.4
5) n = 3.98

''',
'''
Which one is NOT a linear equation?

1) y = 54x*3
2) y = 23x*7
3) y = -x
4) All of the Above
5) None of the Above

''',
'''
What is the formula for finding the surface area for a sphere?

1) 4/3πr**3
2) πr**2
3) 2πrh + 2πr**2
4) πd
5) 4πr**2

''',
'''
Which variable represents the slope?
y = mx + c

1) y
2) m
3) x
4) c
5) None of the above
''',
'''
An isosceles triangle has the top angle of 6x
and a supplementary angle of a base angle is 21x. What are the
measures of the angles of isosceles triangle?

1) 22.5, 78.75, 78.75
2) 108.97, 35.52, 35.52
3) 76.8, 51.6, 51.6
4) 20, 20, 140
5) 43.6, 5.5, 98.53

''',
'''
A sphere fits inside a rectangular box of 6cm by 6cm by 7cm.
What is the greatest possible volume of the sphere? 

1) 113.04 cm*2
2) 110.46 cm*3
3) 113.04 cm*3
4) 110.46 cm*2
5) 142.9 cm*3

''',
'''
If the area of an isosceles triangle is 196 cm**2
and the height is 19.6 cm, what would it's perimeter be?

1) 53.9 cm
2) 64 cm
3) 76 cm
4) 32.43 cm
5) 32.32 cm

'''
]
global answers
global picked
global userans
global ansRandOrder
global score

answers = ['2', '1', '4', '3', '5', '5', '2', '1', '3', '2']
picked = []
userans = []
ansRandOrder = []
score = 0

def nexT():
    global userans
    userans.append(e1.get())
    print(userans)
    print(ansRandOrder)
    global score
    global i
    i = 0
    if userans[i] == ansRandOrder[i]:
        score += 1
    i += 1
    print(score)
    self.destroy()
    ques()

def ques():
    global self
    global e1
    global ansRandOrder
    global picked

    self = Tk()

    w = 500
    h = 375

    ws = self.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = self.winfo_screenheight()

    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)

    self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))

    x = random.randint(0, 9)
    while x in picked:
        x = random.randint(0, 9)

    picked.append(x)

    ansRandOrder.append(answers[x])

    Label(self, text = '\n').pack()

    Label(self, text = questions[x]).pack()

    e1 = Entry(self)

    e1.pack()

    Label(self, text = '\n').pack()

    nex = Button(self, text = 'Next Question', command = nexT).pack()

    self.mainloop()



ques()
```

The result is always `score = 0`.

How can I correctly add the score?

Answer (score 0):

I've experimented a bit with your code and the issue seems to lie elsewhere. For some reason or another the script always compares the wrong answers for the if in nexT. Other times, after restarting the script without clearing old variables, it always thinks the answer is correct.

I think this issue will probably go away if you clean up your code a bit. I'd recommend you rewrite your code as a class, which is a common approach to Tkinter scripts. The main advantages for you would be:

- It's a lot more readable (It'll be easier to debug)
- No more global variables, instead you just refer to the variables as part of the class (self.variable)
- When the program exits (which it doesn't seem to do properly at the moment) you can just finish with something like del MyClass to get rid of the variable clutter. That clutter is probably why the behaviour of this bug changes from time to time.

Have a look at this thread for some good examples and explanations about building a tkinter class-based application:
[Best way to structure a tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17466561/8812091)

As an example for your quiz, it might look something like this: (Non-functional)

```
class Quiz():

    def __init__(self):

        self.questions = []
        self.WriteQuestions()

        self.answers = ['2', '1', '4', '3', '5', '5', '2', '1', '3', '2']
        self.picked = []
        self.userans = []
        self.ansRandOrder = []
        self.score = 0
        #"self." instead of "global"
        # Any def inside this class can refer to self."variable" and use it or update it.

        self.Question()

    def WriteQuestions(self):
        # All your questions here, just so they're out of the way.


    def NextQuestion(self):

        self.userans.append(e1.get())
        self.i = 0
        if self.userans[i] == ansRandOrder[i]:
            self.score += 1
        i += 1
        print(self.score)
        root.destroy() # You'll need to pick a name other than "self" for your tk window
        self.Question() 
        # self is a reserved keyword for classes and shouldn't be used for anything other
        # than telling a class that you're referring to one of its own variables or functions.


    def Question(self):

        # etc...



if __name__ == 'main':

    # set up tkloop here
    # create an instance of the Quiz class, e.g.
    Qz = Quiz()

    # finally, after the loop finishes:

    del Qz # To get rid of the old variables
```